# Multiple rows of cast + divide formulas not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I try to populate a result per col for each of the cast lines, but it gives me an error on each of the lines except the first one. If i just do the first one, it works as i want it too.

Why does it give me an error on the others even though the col names are existing in the referred view?

I tried just one cast line and thats working fine.

```
Select 

cast ([sum nulls_shipment_id3] as float) / [count Total rows by carriername] *100 as [% NULL id3]
,cast ([sum nulls_shipment_id4] as float) / [count Total rows by carriername] *100 as [%null]
,cast ([EA/AH_REF] as float) / [count Total rows by carriername] *100

From dbo.BAS_CT_DATA_COMPLETENESS_vw1
```

Doesnt work (only if i remove the 2nd and 3rd cast formula)
If i run it with all three casts, the following error occurs:

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 
>   Invalid column name 'sum nulls_shipment_id4'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 
>   Invalid column name 'EA/AH_REF'.

Comment: try sum(nulls_shipment_id4), column name goes between parenthesis..  and (ea/ah_ref) with regular parenthesis, not square.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems very clear to me.  You are referencing columns that don't exist.

Comment: Well, do these columns exist?

Comment: Yes the colomns exist, check out the attached screenshot from now, i get stuck now with the division of the second cast line. the first cast line works still fine if i just run that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
cast ([sum nulls_shipment_id3] as float)
```

For the line above, the sum function is not being used correctly. Please fix into:

```
cast (sum([nulls_shipment_id3]) as float)
```

And the other problem is: here- > `,cast ([EA/AH_REF] as float)`, please use regular brackets instead of square ones like: `,cast ((EA/AH_REF) as float)`

Comment: Thanks, but the col name is indeed (sum nulls_shipment_id3) so thats why i put a [ ] in front.

Comment: @Robert can u go to design page of your table and add a screenshot of it to your question please?

Comment: Ok just added the screenshots. I renamed the cols to avoid confusion with col names starting with sum and count. So hopefully its more clear now, i get an error now with the division of the second cast formula. But as said, if i just run the first cast it works totally fine.

Comment: @Robert could u please show us your table design. The actual column names and actual types.

Comment: @Robert btw in your current screenshot, the paranthesis of cast functions are not closed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it, it also ran into error because on col name contained a "/", so renamed that and now it works...

```
Select 
cast (nulls_shipment_id3 as float) / (Total_rows_by_carriername) *100 as [% NULL id3]
,cast (nulls_shipment_id4 as float) / (Total_rows_by_carriername) *100 as [%null]
,cast (nulls_EAAH_REF as float) / (Total_rows_by_carriername) *100 as [% NULLEAH]
From dbo.BAS_CT_DATA_COMPLETENESS_vw1
```